# What is this opamp circuit with diode?

Tags: operational-amplifier

What is this circuit? It's from Yorkville powered sub nx720s input circuitry.

[image: op amp]

Comment: Where does the arrow go?

Comment: @starblue The arrow at the bottom of the circuit is sometimes used as ground symbol.

Comment: The nx720 schematic has "-12dB/OCT HP" above the circuit. Looks like a second order Sallen-Key circuit with a diode to limit the output high voltage?

Comment: The opamp is configured as a voltage follower, so in any normal operational regime, all three terminals will be at the same voltage and the diode will not conduct. The only time it will conduct is if the input signal tries to go more negative than the opamp's output stage is capable of.

Answer (score 8):

It's an acitve high pass filter ([Sallen-Key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sallen_Key_filter) topology), the diode is to clip large negative swings as Dave mentions.

Note for your circuit R1 = R124, R2 = R108, C1 = C69, C2 = C59 in the equations below.

The undamped natural frequency Fo is given by:

[image: Fo]

and the Q is given by:

[image: Q]

So for this filter Fo is 27.43Hz, and the Q is 0.88.
This means the the output will be 20 * log10(0.88) = 1.1dB down at Fo.